# In Laravel, how to display php value in name attribute?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am having following html code in blade file:

```php
@foreach ($engagements as $engagement)
    {!! Form::checkbox('engagements[]', $engagement->id, in_array($engagement->id, $user->privileges->pluck(engagement_id)->toArray()) ? true : false) !!} {{ $engagement->name }}
    {!! Form::select('roles[]', $userRoles, $user->privileges->where(engagement_id, $engagement->id)->first()[role]) !!}
@endforeach`
```

I want to pass `$engagement->id` in `roles[]` as `roles[{{@engegement_id}}]`

However, instead of displaying value of `{{@engegement_id}}`, it is showing it as roles `[{{@engegement_id}}]` in html view source.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
@foreach ($engagements as $engagement)
@php echo $roleWithId = roles[$engagement->id] @endphp
{!! Form::checkbox('engagements[]', $engagement->id, in_array($engagement->id, $user->privileges->pluck(engagement_id)->toArray()) ? true : false) !!} {{ $engagement->name }}
{!! Form::select($roleWithId , $userRoles, $user->privileges->where(engagement_id, $engagement->id)->first()[role]) !!}
@endforeach
```

Make string which you want to pass and store it in variable and pass that variable in `Form` select.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

We can not do like this, it is giving as error saying 'Undefined variable roles' for `@php echo $roleWithId = roles[$engagement->id] @endphp`. However, I tried it in select itself as

`{!! Form::select('roles[@php echo $engagement->id @endphp]', $userRoles, $user->privileges->where(\App\Privilege::COLUMN_ENGAGEMENT_ID, $engagement->   {\App\Engagement::COLUMN_ID})->first()[\App\Privilege::COLUMN_ROLE]) !!}`

However, it is showing it as

`<select name="roles[<?php echo $engagement->id ?>]">` in view source